# Interactive graphs in a web application

Tags: graph, graphviz, interactive, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to create some interactive graph visualizations.  I found Graphviz and was able to output a static graph (as a .png image) in my application using Pydot (Python interface to Graphviz's Dot language), but I want to make my graphs more interactive, e.g. highlight nodes when I mouse over them, make the nodes clickable, is there an interactive web tool I can use to visualize the graphs? However, I need it to visualize (DAG, tree, parent-child).

Comment: Produce SVG output - with Graphviz or other app - and then post-process the SVG file as desired.  Changing node/edge color on mouseover and/ adding "onclick" actions should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use custom HTML components and make them interactive using Javascript. Or Use SVG for that kind of stuff, but I don't think it is clickable yet.
https://github.com/brpapa/recursion-tree-visualizer
Go to this repo, in this he implements a recursion visualizer using graphviz and somehow made it interactive.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @sroush said in the comments, produce the output as SVG and make use of the [href](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/href/) capabilities and the [tooltip](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/tooltip/).

When generating the graph, each node would have a href that calls your backend;  backend will regenerate the graph and respond back with an updated version of the graph.

## Example

```
digraph G {
    a[href="http://localhost/backend/a/children"];
    b[href="http://localhost/backend/b/children"];
    c[href="http://localhost/backend/c/children"];
}
```

User click on node a and gets back a new graph (or the rendered image) that contains the children of node a:

```
digraph G {
    a1[href="http://localhost/backend/a/parent"];
    a2[href="http://localhost/backend/a/parent"];
}
```